# Trying to find a movie about a dad who goes to a fantasy universe to find kids

Tags: story-identification, movie, parallel-universe, dreams

Hey so I tried to find this movie but I couldn't. I only remember vague details but it was about a white family with a dad who I think was estranged to his kids (a son and a younger daughter) and he winds up in some Atlantis-esque dream world where he has to fufill some quest and his kids are in different bodies than their real selves. His son is a black dude and his daughter is brown and he ends up discovering it's them and they end up fufilling the quest/taking down the problem (I don't remember what it was honestly). But if anyone knows what the movie I'm talking about that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: "His son is a black dude and his daughter is brown and he ends up discovering it's them and they end up fufilling the quest/taking down the problem (I don't remember what it was honestly)"

This sounds kind of like a part of "What Dreams May Come" with Robin Williams

Comment: @KevinMilner That was what I thought of too, I'd suggest adding it as an answer (unless it's a dupe and the Op comes back to confirm in comments)